# How to access Maven artifacts timestamp and buil-number from Bamboo?

Tags: maven, bamboo

With Maven 3.3.9 and using Bamboo for a build pipeline, for a given project version (e.g., `2.3.0-SNAPSHOT`), once the artifacts are pushed to Nexus, the name looks like `my-project-2.3.0-20231009.065059-2.jar`.

Where do the `20231009.065059` and the `2` come from? From Maven or Bamboo? I'd like to access them from a later stage of the Bamboo pipeline, but I don't know whether they are already accessible through a variable, or if there's a way to make them accessible.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using a `-SNAPSHOT` version for your maven artifact. Maven repositories ornament such artifacts with extra filename suffixes so that they can keep more iterations of them. This is outlined in [Maven metadata docs](https://maven.apache.org/repositories/metadata.html#the-v-level-metadata) and becomes clearer if you look at [the example metadata file](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml) and how it points to only the latest iteration.

Having said this, the way to consume such snapshot artifacts is using Maven itself, e.g. [dependency:get](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#dependency:get). Alternatively, [register the artifact and download it from another stage/deployment](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/sharing-artifacts-359400060.html#Sharingartifacts-Sharingartifactsbetweenjobs) without going through Nexus.